# Managing MQTT topics in WSO2 MB management console

Tags: mqtt, wso2-message-broker

in WSO2 MB management console I'm trying to restrict read and write access for topics to certain users and roles, but it seems that it only effects JMS but not MQTT messaging, despite WSO2 MB states to support this protocol.

I would like to restrict subscribing and publishing to single roles, so a user can either publish or subscribe to a topic but not both.

Are there any solutions?

Oliver

Comment: Hi Oliver, At the moment MB only authenticates the user credentials when MQTT connections are made. It doesn't do the Authorization part. The only way to get this done is to customize the code base.

Answer (score 0):

Even though mqtt spec didn't specifically define authorization model. Workaround has been implemented recently as an experimental feature for [MB 3.2.0 alpha](https://github.com/wso2/product-mb/releases/tag/v3.2.0-ALPHA). Implementation is based on carbon permission model with a known limitation of permissions can be defined only for static topics. Please note that this will not be visible in wso2 message broker ui permission tree. Please go through draft [documentation](https://wso2.org/jira/secure/attachment/44138/MQTTAuthenticationandAuthorizationExtension.pdf) in public [Jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/MB-1824) for more information.